# Ensuring the windows media player?

Tags: testing, automated-tests

now i'm working in an automation project. In that i had a test case and the test case was i had to ensure a windows media player. I tried out lot but i'm not able..

help me i'm in project deadline.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Retagged, that had nothing to do with Selenium (since that is a testing framework to work with browsers). Also, what have you tried? Show us something that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final String wmp = "C:\\Program Files\\Windows Media Player\\wmplayer.exe";
```

Run the WMP

```
Runtime.exec(wmp);
```

or ensure that that path exists...

```
System.out.println(new File(wmp).exists());
```

This, of course, is true on Windows XP, you may have to adjust the path for x64 Windows or Windows Vista+. This might be helpful in the cause:

```
final String os = System.getProperty("os.name") + " " + System.getProperty("os.arch");
System.out.println(os);
```